# ASP.NET LinkButton doesn't work in iPad

Tags: asp.net, ipad, asplinkbutton

I developped a website with ASP.NET framework. But after tests we saw that link button doesn't works in iPad how can i solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: As long as JS is enabled, it should work just fine.

Comment: I will look at js is enabled or not thanks

Comment: I don't have an iPad my client says that so i have to solve this. I will give feedback about it.

Comment: Thanks Darin, our client's js is disabled so that solved my problem, you don't have answer so i can't give you points :(

Comment: Probably too late to help here but I'm seeing the exact same issue, the project was tested thoroughly on other browsers, the ipad has js enabled and it still fails. I can hold the link button and it gives me a dialog to execute a javascript "open" but nothing happens either way.

Comment: It is solved by it's self i don' t have problem now. You can only enable js :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkButton uses JavaScript to work. I would guess JavaScript is disabled in your iPad or not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem almost: touch the link button and nothing happens.  If I touch and hold, the dialog comes to to open or cancel, with a title that says "javascript".  If I touch "Open" the link works.

This is with an iPod Touch 3, though our users have reported the problem with a variety of iPhones and iPods.  Obviously javascript is enabled since the dialog method works.